# Not converted text/ractive to HTML

Tags: ractivejs

Why not converted text/ractive to HTML.

This is result in browser:

[image]

This is code in page which include template:

[image]

This is the template:

[image]

This is error in console:

[image]

This if instance using the template:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a template. You need to load Ractive in the browser and create a new instance *using* the template:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: '#your-target-element',
  template: '#step-1',
  data: yourData
});
```

Comment: Thank`s for answer! I found, that instance was created, and added picture to my question.